# Mesomere structures are in one line

Tags: line-breaking, chemfig, mhchem

I'm trying to write the mesomeric structures of Phenetol. Here's a short form of the code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemleft[
        \subscheme{
        \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
        \arrow{<->}
        \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
        \arrow{<->}
        \\ % This doesn't work :(
        \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
        }
\chemright]
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Apparently it looks like this:
[image: How it looks like]

As you can see LaTeX doesn't wrap the line. Do you have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Off-topic: `14pt` is not standard font size for article, at compilation you get warning ...

Comment: The chemical formula you show does not belong to phenole but to phenetole (also called ethyl phenyl ether).

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the welcoming! I don't get this warning is it really that bad?

Comment: @leandriis you're right. Sorry my mistake I meant phenetole but I wrote the wrong name. Fixed it ;)

Comment: @TornaxO7, you should correct declare font size. Standard values for article are `10pt` (default),   `11pt` and `12pt`.  Size of your formula depends on font size, You can reduce font size in formula with addng `\small` or `\footnotesize` after `\schemestart`. However, you can increase `\textwidth` by use of the `geometry` package.

Comment: @Zarko ok, fixed the font to `12pt` now but resizing the font doesn't help either (for the mesomeric structures)

Comment: Apart from the line break issue, you might want to use `CH_2` and `CH_3` instead of `CH2` and `CH3`.

Comment: @leandriis good idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok for you?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemleft[
    \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
\chemright.
    \arrow{<->}
    \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
    \arrow{<->}
\schemestop

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\schemestart
\chemleft.
    \chemfig{{CH} * 6( -{CH} ={CH} -C( =[1] \charge{90=\|}{O}^{\oplus} -[7]CH2 -[1]CH3) - \charge{270=\|}{CH}^{\ominus} -{CH} =)}
\chemright]
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah! Good idea with `\chemright.`! Thank you :)